# Pass parameter to return complex result of stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I am successfully able to add my stored procedure via the Update Model from Database wizard. For a stored procedure that does not require any input parameters, I can easily retrieve complex queries.

However, I cannot return the results of my stored procedure which requires an input parameter. I try passing it in my C# class and storing it in "result" as follows:

```
//20 is the value I am passing into my stored procedure    
IEnumerable<MyClass> result = _db.MyStoredProcedure(20).Select(x => new MyClass(){....});
return result;
```

but I am unable to retrieve the results, as 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Select'.

I believe this is because I need to actually have a result type in my Complex Types in the Model Browser. I can create custom ones, however, I cannot get the return values from my stored procedure into these values as there is no way for me to set that parameter.

I do notice in my stored procedure that it has the variable that needs to be initialized in the "Stored Procedures / Functions" folder under the Database.Store location. Is there any way I can set that to be the value that I want to pass? (I checked properties in the model browser for that specific ID)

Or, maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way.

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution for this problem is simple really.

So passing a parameter works as it should. I should actually be passing 20 into the aforementioned example in my question. The problem lies in with the stored procedure itself.

Because the ADO doesn't have a built-in way to set/pass parameters, you need to manually modify your SQL query, to do what the stored procedure is supposed to do. So I modified my stored procedure to print out the contents of what it's supposed to execute, using

```
print result
```

Then copied and pasted the result of your stored procedure from the "messages" (so my select with the parameter I would normally pass). Then I re-edit the function import in my Model Browser, and hit "Get Column Information" and get the complex result type that I specifically want.

It works!